# Not being able to save data in DB. Can anyone tell me the error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to php and mysql and am making a blog website. When I press the submit button its not saving the data in the DB. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code.

My code is:-

```
<body>
<div class="card">
  <h2>Create New Blog</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Title: * <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="image"/><br><br>
  Write about the tilte: *<br><br>
  <textarea name="info" rows="5" cols="90"></textarea><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

 <?php
    include("connect.php");
    $dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $rol='A1';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $info = $_POST['info'];
        if($check !== false){
            $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
            mysqli_query($db,"INSERT into blogdata(userid, title, image, text, role, created) values ('', '$name', '$imgContent', '$info', '$rol', '$dataTime')");
        } 
        else{
            mysqli_query($db,"insert into blogdata(userid, title, image, text, role, created) values ('', '$name', '', '$info', '$rol', '$dataTime')");
    }
}
 ?> 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you specify if and what error is returned? oh and btw your first and third input fields arent closed with />

Comment: Hi I dunno how your table is set up but if your userid is set to auto-increment I'd leave it out of the query rather than having it with an empty value, also if your image doesn't exist the image column has to allow NULL values, other than that we'd kinda need to see an error

Comment: @Daan after closing the first and third input fields, then also same results. And about the error no error is showing. Just when I press submit the page refreshes but data is not stored in DB

Comment: @PaddyHallihan userid is not set to autoincrement and image accepts NULL values

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: N.B. the lack of parameterisation could also be a contributory factor in your queries failing, if the concatenation results in a syntax error - e.g. if one of the fields contains something like an apostrophe, that would break the SQL and result in an error.

Comment: Add some error checking to get mysqli to throw an exception when a query fails, then you can more easily see what's happening: Add ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: If userid does not auto-increment is it also set to allow NULL values?

Comment: Also I just noticed... `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` should be `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">` - without the "name" attribute then this will not be submitted to the server, and then `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` will never be true. Did you not even debug your code to see which lines are actually getting executed?? That's the first basic step you should take with any problem you encounter.

Comment: Lastly I see a logical error - if there is no image uploaded, you store `''` in the database in the image column...instead you should simply set the field to `NULL` - this correctly indicates that there is no value present. An empty string is not the same as "nothing", it's just, well...a string which happens to have no characters. P.S. In fact it's generally considered more efficient not to store the images in the database at all, but to store them on the filesystem, and in the database just store the filename (and path if required) in order to locate the image again later.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson after setting name="submit" it worked and will also keep all the points you mentioned in  mind while writing the code.